# Creating a new column from substrings of original column with different delimiters

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

In my Oracle SQL Developer, I have a table with the following "Name" Column:

```
| NAME |
--------
Joe Smith
John Doe and Jane Doe
Jenny May, Steven Thomas
```

My goal is to create a new column in a new table that flattens the NAME table by separating on `and` and `,` so it will look like:

```
| NEW_NAME |
------------
Joe Smith
John Doe
Jane Doe
Jenny May
Steven Thomas
```

I have the basic logic down for just creating the columns of separation:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(name, 1, INSTR(name,',',1,1)-1) AS NameOne,
SUBSTR(name, INSTR(name,',',1,1)+1, LENGTH(name)) AS NameTwo,
SUBSTR(name, 1,INSTR(name,' and ',1,1)-1) AS NameThree,
SUBSTR(name, INSTR(name,' and ',1,1)+1,LENGTH(name)) AS NameFour
```

But this creates 4 columns. My goal is to have 1 merged column that I can then query against to find the name Im looking for.

Comment: First: In your post you say "split on AND" (capital letters) but everywhere in the example and code you have "and" (lower case). Please clarify what might exist in the actual data. Second: You must handle "and" carefully, since it may also be part of a name. You don't want to split "Anand Gupta" into "An" and "Gupta" - right?

Comment: how many registers do you have? I need to know it because I am thinking about getting some collection to register your goal and bulk it all into the new table. But it depends on your size of data.

Comment: @mathguy you both make really good points but this data is really poorly managed so Im just trying to do "as good as possible" for the use case. There's only about 200 rows of data. To fix the "and" problem, we can add a space before and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause to find the start and end of the delimiters and then get the substring between those bounds:

```sql
WITH bounds ( name, start_pos, end_pos, next_pos ) AS (
  SELECT name,
         1,
         REGEXP_INSTR( name, ',\s*|\s+and\s+', 1, 1, 0, 'i' ),
         REGEXP_INSTR( name, ',\s*|\s+and\s+', 1, 1, 1, 'i' )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT name,
         next_pos,
         REGEXP_INSTR( name, ',\s*|\s+and\s+', next_pos, 1, 0, 'i' ),
         REGEXP_INSTR( name, ',\s*|\s+and\s+', next_pos, 1, 1, 'i' )
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  next_pos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY name SET rn
SELECT CASE end_pos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( name, start_pos )
       ELSE SUBSTR( name, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
       END As name
FROM   bounds
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( NAME ) AS
SELECT 'Joe Smith' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Doe and Jane Doe' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jenny May, Steven Thomas' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alice, Beryl, Carol, Debbie, Eva, Frances, Geri, Holly' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | NAME          |
> | :------------ |
> | Alice         |
> | Beryl         |
> | Carol         |
> | Debbie        |
> | Eva           |
> | Frances       |
> | Geri          |
> | Holly         |
> | Jenny May     |
> | Steven Thomas |
> | Joe Smith     |
> | John Doe      |
> | Jane Doe      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c50f318f251762ba93c50585bd47166)*

Answer (score 1):

I think that for splitting the name, it's better to use the [Split_Part Function](https://paulzipblog.wordpress.com/2020/09/11/split_part-function-for-oracle/). Be careful when you split by 'and' it's can be part of the name.

Secondly, to handle all column in one, you can just use [COALESCE Function](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-comparison-functions/oracle-coalesce/)

```html
select coalesce (NameOne,NameTwo,NameThree,NameFour)
from (

SELECT SUBSTR(name, 1, INSTR(name,',',1,1)-1) AS NameOne,
SUBSTR(name, INSTR(name,',',1,1)+1, LENGTH(name)) AS NameTwo,
SUBSTR(name, 1,INSTR(name,'and',1,1)-1) AS NameThree,
SUBSTR(name, INSTR(name,'and',1,1)+1,LENGTH(name)) AS NameFour
```